# Curl https login

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to login to https://www.reporo.com/login.php using Curl. Here is code I'm using:

```
  <?php
function createPostString($aPostFields) {
    foreach ($aPostFields as $key => $value) {
        $aPostFields[$key] = urlencode($key . '=' . $value);
    }

    return urlencode(implode('&', $aPostFields));
}

$postFields['username'] = 'login';
$postFields['password'] = 'pass';
$postFields['submit'] = ' ';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.reporo.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.reporo.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pl; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  createPostString($postFields));

curl_exec($curl);
header('Location: https://www.reporo.com/analytics/dashboard.php');
curl_close($curl)


?>
```

After using script it redirects me to http://best-payroll-services.info/adder/login.php . Where is the problem ?

After var_dump(curl_getinfo($c)) I've got:

```
'url' => string 'https://www.reporo.com/login.php' (length=32)
  'content_type' => string 'text/html' (length=9)
  'http_code' => int 200
  'header_size' => int 382
  'request_size' => int 192
  'filetime' => int -1
  'ssl_verify_result' => int 20
  'redirect_count' => int 0
  'total_time' => float 0.843
  'namelookup_time' => float 0
  'connect_time' => float 0.109
  'pretransfer_time' => float 0.531
  'size_upload' => float 255
  'size_download' => float 3233
  'speed_download' => float 3835
  'speed_upload' => float 302
  'download_content_length' => float 3233
  'upload_content_length' => float 255
  'starttransfer_time' => float 0.655
  'redirect_time' => float 0
  'certinfo' => 
    array
      empty
  'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
```

Greetings.

Comment: May I ask what exactly are you trying to achieve with this code? Also where do you expect to be redirected to if the login is correct?

Comment: I'm trying to login to reporo.com but it doesn't work ;/

Comment: So, if I have understood you right, you have a script (running on a different server) that should check if you have cookies. If not, the script sends post login data to a remote script (located @ reporo.com) and then redirects. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to auto login and redirect to: https://www.reporo.com/analytics/dashboard.php. There should be header( 'Location: https://www.reporo.com/analytics/dashboard.php'); but it doesn't change anything, because script can't login ;/

Comment: I think the problem comes when you redirect to `https://www.reporo.com/analytics/dashboard.php`. When using `curl` to post data to the login script you're storing the cookies you received in file. Those cookies are not passed to the browser that's executing the script. Thus your login checks at `https://www.reporo.com/analytics/dashboard.php` fails. It is either that, or what @NightHawk pointed out.

Comment: I've edited some code irrespective of cookies (in the Question post) but it still doesn't work. Hmm. It can't send login datas to reporo.com/login.php ;/

Comment: As I said in my previous comment - you probably need to pass the cookies you're receiving via `curl` to the user's browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are wrong with this script.

- You need to change the relative path of cookies:

  ```
  if ( file_exists( 'cookies.txt' ) )
  ```

  to an absolute

  ```
  if ( file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ).'/cookies.txt' ) )
  ```

  so that you're sure it's checking the right file.
- Also `str_replace( '/', '', $_SERVER[ "PHP_SELF" ] );` is a return function. That means you need to store the returned value:

  ```
  $redirect_url = str_replace( '/', '', $_SERVER[ "PHP_SELF" ] );
  header('Location:'.$redirect_url);
  ```

I've slightly modified your code to this:

```
function connect( $url, $post = '' )
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.100 Safari/534.30' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__.'/cookies.txt' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  __DIR__.'/cookies.txt' );
    $result = curl_exec( $curl );
    curl_close( $curl );
    return $result;
}

$login_data[ 'username' ] = $_POST['login'];
$login_data[ 'password' ] = $_POST['password'];

foreach ( $login_data as $key => $value ) {
    $post_items[ ] = $key.'='.$value;
}
$post_string = implode( '&', $post_items );

if ( file_exists( __DIR__.'/cookies.txt' ) ) {
    // Cookies exist, point to a secured page?
    echo connect( 'https://yourhost/secure.php')
}
else {
    // Cookies don't exist post to a login page and redirect to a secured page?
    connect( 'https://yourhost/login.php', $post_string )
    $redirect_url = str_replace( '/', '', $_SERVER[ "PHP_SELF" ] );
    header( 'Location: '.$redirect_url );

}
```

Comment: I used your code and it still doesn't work, I've got info: Please try again: Please Login, when I redirect to site after login: https://reporo.com/analytics/dashboard.php, so evererything is good, but it doesn't login ;/ ;)

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect that you're not quite sure what you're doing OR you simply can't explain it. Is this script meant to be used to login remotely to another site or you're using it to login to your own site?

Comment: It login to another site that is not my, actually nothing more ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the website it redirects to belongs to you, because the only thing in that code that redirects is the following line:

```
header( 'Location: '.$_SERVER[ "PHP_SELF" ] );
```

I'm guessing the problem is with:

```
if ( file_exists( 'cookies.txt' ) )
```

That file doesn't appear to exist, which is why it's running:

```
connect( 'https://www.reporo.com/login.php', $post_string );
str_replace( '/', '', $_SERVER[ "PHP_SELF" ] );
header( 'Location: '.$_SERVER[ "PHP_SELF" ] );
```

Comment: cookies.txt exists and there is: .www.reporo.com FALSE / FALSE 0 PHPSESSID 8fb5f0016b3eb25c9dd23856acdfe47f

Comment: `file_exists( 'cookies.txt' )` returns true? It can't return true if PHP is redirecting you.

Comment: In the question post I edited code but it still doesn't work ;/ Cookies path is right. I've checked this out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script I wrote to login to the Reporo site and download the overall advertiser stats for a particular date (specified in the url). I'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for.

```
// Login & download stats in CSV format
function get_stats($login_url, $username, $password, $login_button, $csv_title, $download_url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url);
    $post_fields = 'username='.urlencode($username).'&password='.urlencode($password);
    // Some sites don't send this variable, hence the check
    if(trim(urlencode($login_button)) != ''){
        $post_fields .= '&'.$login_button.'='.$login_button;
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
    curl_exec($ch);

    // Prevent the script from timing out
    set_time_limit(0);

    $fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/'.$csv_title, 'w+');//This is the file where we save the information
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $download_url);//Here is the file we are downloading
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}

// Set REPORO variables
$rep__login_url = 'https://www.reporo.com/login.php';
$rep_un = 'USERNAME';
$rep_pw = 'PASSWORD';
$rep_login_butt = 'submit';
$rep_csv = 'reporo_stats.csv';
// In the url, list= YOUR CAMPAIGN IDS (comma seperated)
$rep_dl_url = 'https://www.reporo.com/analytics/data.php?type=AdvertiserEntity&start=2012-10-17&end=2012-10-17&entity=client&list=1234,5678,9101,1121,3141&format=csv';

// Call get_stats function
get_stats($rep__login_url, $rep_un, $rep_pw, $rep_login_butt, $rep_csv, $rep_dl_url);
```