# Send form using curl https site

Tags: php, curl, https

I have a problem. I want to send a form using curl but it doesn't work. The form is in this url: https://www.reporo.com/analytics/inventory-advertiser-banner.php?clientid=1234&campaignid=12345&type=smrc .

Here is the form code:

```
<form name='bannerForm' id='bannerForm' action='inventory-advertiser-banner-update.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

The problem is that when I enter to browser this url: `https://www.reporo.com/analytics/inventory-advertiser-banner-update.php` - it redirects me to the login page. The same when I'm using curl and here is my problem.

I don't know why I can send form only manually when I click "Submit" in the form page - this url: `http://reporo.com/analytics/inventory-advertiser-banner.php?clientid=1234&campaignid=12345&type=smrc`

What can be the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: Solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333243/curl-https-login

Comment: But this solution doesn't work ;/